# Validation for text field

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form with the text area called name, I cant seem to be able to validate this field even though all the drop down lists are navigation, I have tried lots of different combinations but still not working, have I missed something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_form() {


    if ( document.form.title.selectedIndex == 0 )
    {
        alert ( "Please Select Title." );
        return false;
    }
    if ( document.form.time.selectedIndex == 0 )
    {
        alert ( "Please Select Time." );
        return false;
    }
    if ( document.form.membership.selectedIndex == 0 )
    {
        alert ( "Please Select Membership." );
        return false;
    }
    if ( document.form.name.length < 1 )
    {
        alert ( "Please Enter Name" );
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried jQuery which provides a validation module?

Answer (score 1):

try `document.forms[0].title.selectedIndex`

Comment: excellent the document.forms[0].title.selectedIndex works, thanks very much for that

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.form.name.value.length` instead.

Comment: Please note, however, name is a bad id since it *might* be a reserved word, not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Usually enough is check whether is length of value  of either textarea or input.

```
if( field.value.length ) {

}
```

Bellow code, which maybe that you need it.

```
 <form id="myform" method='post' onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <select name="select1">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="val11"> Option </option>
        <option value="val12"> Option </option>
    </select>

    <select name="select2">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="val21"> Option </option>
        <option value="val22"> Option </option>
    </select>
    <select name="select3" >
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="val31"> Option </option>
        <option value="val32"> Option </option>

    </select>

    <textarea name='description'> </textarea>
    <input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

and script for this:

```
var validate  = function( form ) {
   // argument is a form from which function was called

   // Collect elements to an array which will be validated.
   var inputs  = [].concat.apply(
        [].concat.apply([], form.getElementsByTagName("select")),
        form.getElementsByTagName("textarea")                                
   );


   for( var i = 0, l = inputs.length, input; input = inputs[i], i < l; i++ ) {

        if( !input.value  ) {
            //In case when some select don't have a value, or empty string is provided        alert( input.name);
           // Message will be showed
           alert( "Field " + input.name + " cannot be empty!");  
           return false; // return false, form will not submitted
       }
   };  
   return true; // if all of selects have a properly value;
};
```

Demo on http://jsfiddle.net/4hBuF/